# Two ways of registration rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise, rubygems

I have two type of users: master and customer (like freelance). I use devise gem.

How to create two ways of registration easier?

Comment: Store them in the same model class. Assign master/customer role via extra column, STI oder related entity (i.e. a Role-Model)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best is to create a STI

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end

class User::Master < User
end

class User::Customer < User
end
```

Install devise gem

```
rails g devise:install
```

Configure routes:

```
devise_for :users, skip: [:registrations]
devise_for :masters, skip: :sessions
devise_for :customers, skip: :sessions
```

Generate devise views

```
rails g devise:views
```

After you create helpers for the methods currency but adapting them to STI.